# Cannot create JTable due to being unable to resolve constructor error

Tags: java, swing

In my code, I have made a Rentals class as shown here:

```
public class Rentals {
    protected int RentalID;
    protected int CustomerID;
    protected int MovieID;
    protected Date DateRented;
    protected Date DateDue;

    public Rentals(int rentalID, int customerID, int movieID, Date dateRented, Date dateDue) {
        RentalID = rentalID;
        CustomerID = customerID;
        MovieID = movieID;
        DateRented = dateRented;
        DateDue = dateDue;
    }

    public int getRentalID() {
        return RentalID;
    }

    public void setRentalID(int rentalID) {
        RentalID = rentalID;
    }

    public int getCustomerID() {
        return CustomerID;
    }

    public void setCustomerID(int customerID) {
        CustomerID = customerID;
    }

    public int getMovieID() {
        return MovieID;
    }

    public void setMovieID(int movieID) {
        MovieID = movieID;
    }

    public Date getDateRented() {
        return DateRented;
    }

    public void setDateRented(Date dateRented) {
        DateRented = dateRented;
    }

    public Date getDateDue() {
        return DateDue;
    }

    public void setDateDue(Date dateDue) {
        DateDue = dateDue;
    }
}
```

In the main class, I create 2 array lists, RentalList and Columns, consisting of Rentals and Strings respectively. I also create a JTable called Display for later use. I then make a connection to my MS Azure SQL Database, and extract the relevant data into the two aforementioned array lists. After retrieving this data, I tried to use the array lists to add parameters to the Display JTable, following this [Java Swing JTable Tutorial](https://youtu.be/wniqpx8OQxo?t=224) (Timestamped), but I kept getting this error:

```
java: no suitable constructor found for JTable(java.util.ArrayList<com.company.Rentals>,java.util.ArrayList<java.lang.String>)
    constructor javax.swing.JTable.JTable(javax.swing.table.TableModel,javax.swing.table.TableColumnModel) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; java.util.ArrayList<com.company.Rentals> cannot be converted to javax.swing.table.TableModel)
    constructor javax.swing.JTable.JTable(int,int) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; java.util.ArrayList<com.company.Rentals> cannot be converted to int)
    constructor javax.swing.JTable.JTable(java.util.Vector,java.util.Vector) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; java.util.ArrayList<com.company.Rentals> cannot be converted to java.util.Vector)
    constructor javax.swing.JTable.JTable(java.lang.Object[][],java.lang.Object[]) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; java.util.ArrayList<com.company.Rentals> cannot be converted to java.lang.Object[][])
```

for the line with `Display = new JTable(RentalList, Columns);`.

Main class:

```
public class Main {
    public static JTable Display;
    public static ArrayList<Rentals> RentalList =  new ArrayList<Rentals>();
    public static ArrayList<String> Columns = new ArrayList<String>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String ConnectionURL = "___"; //HIDDEN, IN THE ACTUAL CODE IT DOES CONNECT
        ResultSet rs;

        // Open a connection
        try(Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(ConnectionURL);
            Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
        ) {
            rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM [dbo].[Rentals]");
            while (rs.next()) {
                Rentals rental = new Rentals(0, 0, 0, null, null);
                rental.setRentalID(rs.getInt(1));
                rental.setCustomerID(rs.getInt(2));
                rental.setMovieID(rs.getInt(3));
                rental.setDateRented(rs.getDate(4));
                rental.setDateDue(rs.getDate(5));
                RentalList.add(rental);
            }
            
            rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = N'Rentals'");
            while (rs.next()) {
                Columns.add(rs.getString(1));
            }
        }
        catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Display = new JTable(RentalList, Columns);
    }
```

I have tried writing it as `Display = new JTable(RentalList.toString(), Columns);`, but the error remains.
Does anyone know if I have done anything wrong, or if I am trying to insert parameters that do not fit the requirements, and if so how would I correct this?

Comment: Do you see any constructor that can take an `ArrayList` in [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/JTable.html#constructor-summary)?

Comment: aside: do use the java.time classes (__not__ the very oudated and buggy Date/Calendar)

Answer (score 1):

As you can see from [JTable's documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/JTable.html) there is no constructor accepting two (Array)Lists. There's for example one that accepts a Vector of Vectors (for the data) and a Vector of arbitrary objects (for the column names).

So, either you use one of the constructors available, which means that you'd need to convert your data, or what I'd prefer, create a custom table model.

```
public class RentalsTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {
    private List<Rentals> data;
    private List<String> columnNames = List.of("Rental ID", "Customer ID", "Movie ID", "Date Rented", "Date Due");

    public RentalsTableModel(Collection<? extends Rentals> rentals) { 
        data = new ArrayList<>(rentals); 
    }

    @Override
    public Class<?> getColumnClass(int col) {
        return (col == 3 || col == 4) ? Date.class : Integer.class;
    }

    @Override
    public int getRowCount() { return data.size(); }

    @Override
    public int getColumnCount() { return columnNames.size(); }

    @Override
    public String getColumnName(int ix) { return columnNames.get(ix); }

    @Override
    public Object getValueAt(int row, int col) {
        Rentals rental = data.get(row);
        switch (col) {
            case 0: return rental.getRentalID();
            case 1: return rental.getCustomerID();
            case 2: return rental.getMovieID();
            case 3: return rental.getDateRented();
            case 4: return rental.getDateDue();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

With such a model you'd instantiate your JTable as follows

```
List<Rentals> rentals = ...;
RentalsTableModel model = new RentalsTableModel(rentals);
JTable table = new JTable(model);
```

Be warned: all code in here is untested and can contain errors and typos. It's just a sketch to give you an idea how it could look like. Of course, you can implement a more generic TableModel, or one for SQL-Queries, too.